# Seeking global (worldwide) list of street abbreviations?

Tags: data, address, global

I'm looking for a list of street and road names abbreviations (e.g Street -> St, Avenue -> Ave. and so on). All I've seen are country-specific lists. Is there a global one, or at least a dataset to extract it from?

I've found this list: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Name_finder:Abbreviations, and it's quite good, but obviously lacks countries/languages and even items for some of sections.

---

the OSM "short_name" tag is of no use cause it's absent for practically every road.

Comment: I think this type of question may be more suited to the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange but if you decide to ask it there be sure to check their Help to make sure that it is on-topic.

Comment: While reading your question, I'm wondering if this is really the problem you need solved. Just a thought. Are you trying to parse street address info that varying abbreviations? Are you trying to standardize addresses?

Comment: @Joseph Yes, it's the first option basically, working on a way to improve a lookup engine.

Comment: @flire Oh. Well, I've worked with a API for these lookups before ([SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com)) but I don't know where they get their data.

Comment: I recommend them if you're open to using a different service rather than building your own.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is a set of streets and other worldwide data in [OSM Data Extracts](http://download.geofabrik.de/) , find region or country, download zip files and there you will see a layer called "roads". The field "name" contains the full name of a roads.

Talking about abbreviations, I think if there are another opensource projects which have a worldwide dataset, probably there you will find what you need.

Comment: Yes, thaks for the advice. I looked at the OSM road data and considered using the "short_name" tag. Unfortunately, the tag is empty for most of the roads and really useless for getting data for the aforementioned dictionary.